# serverSideRender does not render "preview" html inside Gutenberg block

Tags: plugins, block-editor

I've pulling pulling my hair for the last 2 days with this and searching did not result in any solution to the issue I am having.

I wanted to use **<serverSideRender />** to load dynamic content in the front-end as well as see the generated content in the Gutenberg editor. I tested it with the simple example given on the [Gutenberg doc page](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/tutorials/block-tutorial/creating-dynamic-blocks/).

Here is the JS code:

```
const { registerBlockType }                 = wp.blocks;
const { serverSideRender }                  = wp.serverSideRender

registerBlockType( 'gutenberg-examples/example-dynamic', {
    title: 'Example: last post',
    icon: 'megaphone',
    category: 'widgets',

    edit: function( props ) {

        return [

            <p>serverSideRender should appear here:</p>,
            <serverSideRender
                block="gutenberg-examples/example-dynamic"
                attributes={ props.attributes }
            />
        ];
    },
} );
```

PHP Code:

```
function gutenberg_examples_dynamic_render_callback( $attributes, $content ) {
    $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( array(
        'numberposts' => 1,
        'post_status' => 'publish',
    ) );
    if ( count( $recent_posts ) === 0 ) {
        return 'No posts';
    }
    $post = $recent_posts[ 0 ];
    $post_id = $post['ID'];
    return sprintf(
        '<a class="wp-block-my-plugin-latest-post" href="%1$s">%2$s</a>',
        esc_url( get_permalink( $post_id ) ),
        esc_html( get_the_title( $post_id ) )
    );
}

function gutenberg_examples_dynamic() {

    register_block_type( 'gutenberg-examples/example-dynamic', array(
        'render_callback' => 'gutenberg_examples_dynamic_render_callback'
    ) );

}
add_action( 'init', 'gutenberg_examples_dynamic' );
```

The front-end displays the post as intended. Screenshot below:

[image]

But in Gutenberg the block does not show the dynamic content. In theory I should see the same thing as the front-end right? Or am I missing something?

This is what I see in Gutenberg:

[image]

As you can see, none of the dynamic content is rendered and there aren't any errors in the console either.

What am I doing wrong? Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Ok, after spending the whole day searching and reading I found the solution. It seems that `ServerSideRender` should be de-structured from `wp.components` and **NOT** from `wp.serverSideRender`

After replacing

```
const { serverSiderRender: ServerSideRender }   = wp.serverSideRender;
```

with

```
const { ServerSideRender } = wp.components;
```

And

```
// <serverSideRender
<ServerSideRender 
    block="gutenberg-examples/example-dynamic"
    attributes={ props.attributes }
/>
```

All works fine now

[image]

Hope this helps someone. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You’ll have to alias serverSideRender to use it in JSX.

```
const { serverSiderRender: ServerSideRender } = wp.serverSideRender
```

Comment: Hi @Welcher, thanks for replying, appreciate it. I change the line in the JS file to what you suggested but that did not make any difference. Still works fine in front-end but nothing happens in the editor. I removed the block and added it again. Still no luck. I also changed the ``<serverSideRender />`` to ``<ServerSideRender />`` like I've seen in many tutorials but that throws an error "Error: Minified React error #130;"

Answer (score 0):

From what I have read, ServerSideRender in `wp.components` in depreciated. I had to modify the `index.asset.php` file to include 'wp-server-side-render' as a dependency.

For example:

```php
<?php
return array(
    'dependencies' => array(
        'wp-blocks',
        'wp-element',
        'wp-polyfill',
        'wp-block-editor',
        'wp-server-side-render'
    ),
    'version' => '0.1'
);
```